# Filling jComboBox in Java in Netbeans 6.5

Tags: java

I am a C# programmer that wants to learn Java. So I was filling a combobox in MS Visual C# by filling a datatable or dataset and show in DisplayMember(NAME), ValueMember (ID).

I searched for binding jcombobox but Google did not help me. Would someone give an example for binding please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NetBeans Platform CRUD Application Tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html)